# Scala Pattern match the result of a method during unit testing

Tags: scala, unit-testing

I am unit testing a scala method which returns a string of the following form

> SELECT col1 FROM tableName WHERE ts <= 1533499389

The integer value is epoch and would change on every execution. I was wondering if there is a way in Scala to just match the pattern to assert the value returned

Pattern can be something like :

> SELECT col1 FROM tableName WHERE ts <= {}

Comment: You have a method that returns a SQL query as a String? You're probably doing something wrong. Please use prepared statements or some other SQL API that will protect you from SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use match pattern,

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime

import org.scalatest.{FunSuite, Matchers}

class SqlSpec extends FunSuite with Matchers {

  def fn = s"""SELECT col1 FROM tableName WHERE ts <= ${OffsetDateTime.now().toEpochSecond}"""

  test("whatever") {
    fn.matches("SELECT col1 FROM tableName WHERE ts <= \\d{10}") should be(true)
  }

}
```